# Type is known, but method refers to missing type

Tags: java

I'm not very experienced with java and Eclipse and I'm getting the following problem:

I'm writing something like:

```
Point3D myPoint = myClass.myMethod(arg);
```

And I got the error:

> the method myMethod(myType arg) refers to the missing type Point3D.

However the class `Point3D` is known, I can create an object of this type (`Point3D`) without error and I got `Point3D` methods from auto-completion.

Comment: It could be a different `Point3D` than the one imported...

Comment: Thanks for the response, so I should try to clean my jar files and check if I got another Point3D ?

Comment: no, if you verify that the `Point3D` returned by your method invocation is not the one you imported, since you can't import both, you'll simply need to refer to it with its canonical name, that is the `full.package.ClassName`.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand what u said, assuming that my class Point3D is in package.Point3D, I should write something like this :
        package.Point3D myPoint = myClass.myMethod(arg);
But I still have the same error.

Comment: *if* they are two different `Point3D`s, which is yet to be verified, you should take a look at the method's API and find out what exactly is the package + class name. Then use that as reference.

Comment: Had the same problem. A `mvn clean` solved it.

Comment: In Eclipse, sometimes "Project->Clean..." can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are evidently using a different implementation of `Point3D` in the class where you have declared the method than where you are calling it.

Go to the declaration of `myMethod` and check that the import statement for `Point3D` in that class is the same as the import statement in the class where you are calling `myMethod`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, in myMethod, I've an import of package.Point3D and I've put the same import in my main file (where I call myMethod) but it says it's unused. I'll investigate more to see what is the other Point3D (it's not my code so I don't know very well what it could be).

Comment: Hmmm OK. If you need more help then post more of your code so we can see it too! :)

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue, I solved it by changing the order of import.
I put the class which make the issue at the top of import list, after package, then the IDE(VS code) makes no alert.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved with casting returning value of method to needed class - in your case Point3D

```
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long,HotelInfHQ> HASH_HOTELINF = new  ConcurrentHashMap<Long,HotelInfHQ>();

////

public static HotelInfHQ getHotelInfByKey (Long key){   
    return (HotelInfHQ)HASH_HOTELINF.get(key);
}
```

and in another class call was like

```
getHotelInfByKey(value);
```

Although ConcurrentHashMap HASH_HOTELINF was parametrized and Eclipse didn't show any mistake in return string,  it was not obvious to it what class of object it returns at the point of method call

Answer (score 0):

Might depend on your context, but I was having the same issue too until I compiled it. Make sure that Eclipse didn't hide your import statements at the top of your program by minimizing a couple lines. I accidentally imported a file from a previous project of the same name and it hid the import statement at the top: "import A3.BST;". Just expand out to see your lines and delete the import statement and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled Java module System without actually configuring it correctly this happens. I decided to remove the Java module system and use only the maven dependencies. In "Java Build Path" ensure that the Classpath dependencies are defined correctly.